# Discrd.py python 3.6 user requested Join-leave channel

Tags: discord, python-3.6, discord.py

I'm making a bot that has a join-leave message but I need to set it so that a user can send specify what channel they want the message to be posted in.

Example:
User: .joinleave
Bot: Please send the channel id you want the join-leave messages to be sent.
User: [Channel-ID]
Bot: Thank you! Join-leave messages will be posted in [Channel-ID]

What I have so far:

```
   @client.event
   async def on_member_join(member):
     role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Member')
     await client.add_roles(member, role)
     embed = discord.Embed(title="{}'s info".format(member.name), description="New Member!!!", color='Blue')
     embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.name, inline=True)
     embed.add_field(name="ID", value=member.id, inline=True)
     embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status, inline=True)
     embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=member.top_role)
     embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=member.joined_at)
     embed.add_field(name="Created", value=member.created_at)
     embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
     inlul = client.get_channel("")

     await client.send_message(inlul, embed=embed)
```

I figured I would make a command that would be '.joinleave' and that's where they would enter the channel ID. I just don't know how I would save that info from multiple servers and it be different per server. Then pass it to the @client.event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a global [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) variable that uses the server ID as the keys and the channel ID as the values. The problem is saving it to [storage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm). I have two solutions to this.

### One File

Make a file, called `server_channels.txt` or something, and have a line for each server. First, it will show the server ID, then the channel ID. It would look something like this:

```
[server id 1] [channel id 1] # just replace each of these
[server id 2] [channel id 2]
...
```

You'll need to parse this file whenever the bot starts and put it into a dictionary. You also need to update the file whenever there is an update to the dictionary.

### Multiple Files

Instead of reading through an entire file, make a directory called `server_channels` or something. It will contain a file for each server. The name of the file is the server ID, and the file will contain the channel ID.